# Voiceover is not speaking programmatically focused element

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

In my page I have few divs with role="radio" ( ~20 such divs ). Now when the user selects any of the radio, I am programmatically setting focus to "Continue" button. I was expecting that as soon as this button will get foucs, screen reader ( VoiceOver ) will speak "Continue Button". But it doesn't ( Button gets the focus but it is not spoken ).  I want screenReader to speak it so that visually impaired person can hear and perform the action.

If you have faced similar issue then how did you tackled it?

Comment: Provide the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing might create an accessibility violation. Take a look at this

http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html

Of course, there are scenarios where setting focus like that IS appropriate behavior and this might be one of those. Can you share your code?